# How to make inner DIV width a percent of outer div width that is set to auto

Tags: css, resize, image-resizing, fluid-layout, window-resize

Wapper contains a outer DIV (the group DIV that contains the IMG) and 3 inner DIVs (overlays).
I need to position and size the overlay DIVs relative to it's container.
The problem is that the container's width is set to auto;  so The when I set DIVa to width
The width of the outer DIV is set to auto, so that when user resizes window, it resizes accordingly.

Here's a JFIDDLE version: http://jsfiddle.net/6XsVB/

```
This is what I get: (it's using the % of the main wrapper. Not the parent DIV)
    +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |  +--------------------------------------------------------+             |
    |  | Group DIV. Height:100%; Width:auto; (contains IMG)     |             |
    |  | +---------------++------------------------------++-----|------------+| This is
    |  | |               ||                              ||     |            || the main 
    |  | |               ||                              ||     |            || wrapper
    |  | |    overlay1   ||          overlay2            ||    overlay3      || DIV 
    |  | |               ||                              ||     |            || Width:1200px 
    |  | |     DIV a     ||            DIV b             ||     |DIV c       || Height:70%  
    |  | |               ||                              ||     |            ||   
    |  | |   Width:20%;  ||        Width:50%;            ||   Width:30%;     || The width of 
    |  | |  Height:100%  ||        Height:100%;          ||   Height:100%;   || this wrapper 
    |  | |               ||                              ||     |            || will change 
    |  | |               ||                              ||     |            || depending on
    |  | |               ||                              ||     |            || the amt of 
    |  | |               ||                              ||     |            || groups used
    |  | +---------------++------------------------------++-----|------------+| inside it 
    |  +--------------------------------------------------------+             | manually.  
    +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+

This is the goal:
    +--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |  +--------------------------------------------------------+              |
    |  | Group DIV. Height:100%; Width:auto; (contains IMG)     |              |
    |  | +-----------++------------------------++-------------+ | This is      |
    |  | |           ||                        ||             | | the main     |
    |  | |           ||                        ||             | | wrapper      |
    |  | |  overlay1 ||       overlay2         ||  overlay3   | | DIV          |
    |  | |           ||                        ||             | | Width:1200px |
    |  | |   DIV a   ||         DIV b          ||    DIV c    | | Height:70%   |
    |  | |           ||                        ||             | |              |
    |  | | Width:20%;||     Width:50%;         || Width:30%;  | | The width of |
    |  | |Height:100%||     Height:100%;       || Height:100%;| | this wrapper |
    |  | |           ||                        ||             | | will change  |
    |  | |           ||                        ||             | | depending on |
    |  | |           ||                        ||             | | the amt of   |
    |  | |           ||                        ||             | | groups used  |
    |  | +-----------++------------------------++-------------+ | inside it    |
    |  +--------------------------------------------------------+ manually.    |
    +--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

NOTE: I need the width set to auto bc the image needs to resize when the browser window resizes.

Comment: As an aside, I suggest you learn how to use [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). I can't believe you made this awesome picture.

Comment: i like the picture as well :D. but its helpful and time saving if you provide a sample code, preferably in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) as @MiniRagnarok said before.

Comment: a question about the Group DIV. The image is an image or a background of the div?

Comment: This image is pure awesomeness. You could make money by creating mockups with ASCII characters!

Comment: Im a creative dir... not a coder... ha! thanks, but I'm stuck on this one.

Comment: The IMG is a placed image (not a background image)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6XsVB/

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not positive what your problem is. I think you're saying that you want the `group` class to be the same width as the image. If that's true then I would think you'd have to use javascript to do that. The problem is that there's no way to figure out the image proportion using CSS. In your case you need to figure out what the width is based on what the height is.

For example, your image width to height ratio is 5/3. If the height was 430px then take 430 and multiply it by 3/5 to get a width of 258px. Then you would manually set the width of `.group` to 258px.

Comment: can't use fixed px for width... needs to be %

Comment: @CharlesNYC I know. I've started the jsfiddle so that you had something to work with. There was no way anyone was going to be able to help you without some code.

Comment: here is the jsfiddle:   http://jsfiddle.net/6XsVB/
If it can't be done without JS, then the function of the JS would be:

on window resize(get new width of "groupDIV"), then make that X.

Comment: here is the jsfiddle:   http://jsfiddle.net/6XsVB/
If it can't be done without JS, then the function of the JS would be:

on window resize(get new user-width of "groupDIV"), then make that foo. Then, new width of GROUPDIV is foo+"px".

I think this will conver the auto width to foopx; then the percentages will work.

Comment: @CharlesNYC No. This would be something that you would write yourself.

Comment: @CharlesNYC You asked me if this was a plugin. I said no, you would have to write the JavaScript code yourself. I wasn't saying that you were capable of doing so. I was just answering the question. Anyway this is much easier than you think. I have little JavaScript experience myself. What you need to do is figure how to target the element in question. Perform the math that I supplied. Finally you would then alter the width. Try searching for how to do those things if you don't know how.